# TYPO3 file upload resource manager

Tags: file-upload, typo3, resourcemanager, typo3-flow

I made file upload according to http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/ResourceManagement.html

I have this error: **Invalid type encountered: '\TYPO3\Flow\Resource\Resource'**

*Code*

Controler:

```
class Tx_PromConf_Controller_RegistrationController extends Tx_Extbase_MVC_Controller_ActionController { 
/**
    * Imports a passport
    *
    * @param Tx_PromConf_Domain_Model_Passport $passport The new passport
    * @return void
    */
    public function passportUploadAction(Tx_PromConf_Domain_Model_Passport $passport) {
        $this->passportRepository->add($passport);
        $this->forward('index');
    }
}
```

Model

```
class  Tx_PromConf_Domain_Model_Passport extends Tx_Extbase_DomainObject_AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var \TYPO3\Flow\Resource\Resource
     */
    protected $originalResource;

    /**
     * @param string $title
     * @return void
     */
    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\Flow\Resource\Resource $originalResource
     * @return void
     */
    public function setOriginalResource(\TYPO3\Flow\Resource\Resource $originalResource) {
        $this->originalResource = $originalResource;
    }

    /**
     * @return \TYPO3\Flow\Resource\Resource
     */
    public function getOriginalResource() {
        return $this->originalResource;
    }

    /**
     * __construct
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        //Do not remove the next line: It would break the functionality
        $this->initStorageObjects();
        $this->setTitle('PassportScan');
    }

    /**
     * Initializes all Tx_Extbase_Persistence_ObjectStorage properties.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function initStorageObjects() {

    }
}
```

Form

```
<f:form action="passportUpload" controller="Registration" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
            object="{passport}" objectName="passport">
        <br />
        <div>
            <f:translate key="tx_promconf_passport_upload.sentense" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="max-size">
            <f:form.upload class="btn" name="originalResource" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="max-size">
            <f:form.submit name="mySubmit" class="btn btn-l" value="<f:translate key='tx_promconf_passport_upload.ok' />" />
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-r" value="<f:translate key='tx_promconf_passport_upload.cancel' />" />    
        </div>
    </f:form>
```

Comment: Which TYPO3 and Extbase version do you use? When does the error occur - when calling the upload form or when uploading a file?

Comment: TYPO3 v4.7And error occurs when I call the upload form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using *TYPO3 CMS*:
You will not find the class `TYPO3\Flow\Resource\Resource` there.

Therefore you are bound to **Extbase** classes. If you are using TYPO3 6.x, you might want to look either in the Extbase namespace or somewhere here: `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceInterface`.
But most probably, the easiest way is to look for another tutorial on file uploads with Extbase.

If you're developing a standalone FLOW application, I don't have a precise answer.

Comment: Yes I am using TYPO3 CMS. But I cannot find that Resource anywhere. Maybe it is because of the version.

Comment: Most probably. In 4.7, the namespace concept is not implemented consistently. I recommend looking out for another tutorial.